# Ruby On Rails Update failed still

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have try many things but still failed, i want to implement a edit and update action here.
Below is my code

home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @inputs = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @input = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @input = Person.new(input_params)
    respond_to do |x|
    if @input.save
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
    else
        x.html {render :action => 'new'}
    end
   end
  end

  def show
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |x|
      if @input.update(input_params)
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
      else
        x.html {render :edit}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def input_params
    params.require(:inputs).permit(:name, :weight, :height, :color, :age)
  end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Data</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Show', home_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', home_index_path %>
```

form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :@input do |person| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :name %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :weight %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :weight %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :height %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :height %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :color %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :color %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :age %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= person.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes are correct, i can lead me to the edit page, however, it shows,
[first problem, edit with no data pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhi3.png)

New updated

[image: Second problem, when click on button, directly go to this page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`,

```
<%= form_for @input do |x| %>
...
```

and then (depending on what @input actually is!)

```
<%= x.text_field :age %>
```

Comment: Your issue is with the routes. Rails works by convention, if you follow the patterns, "it just works", if you don't then you have to add some configure. i've update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not binding your form to your method.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

gives an overview, but I'd suggest something like this for your edit:

```
<%= form_for @input do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

and in your partial - which should be _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<p><label for = "input_name">Name</label>:
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

etc.. Now assuming you have set your routes correctly, it will go back to your update method. If you have *not* set up your routes in the way rails expects, then you should use:

```
<%= form_for @article, url: **your_update_path** do |f| %>
```

Just add the routes path that points to your update method, when you run rake routes.